# Making the Exception the header of a message and sending it to an error queue in Spring Integration

Tags: java, error-handling, rabbitmq, spring-integration

I'm pretty new to SI and I'm trying to make it so when an exception occurs, the exception becomes the header of the message that caused the exception, and then is sent on to a designated error queue instead of the regular queue. I went through the sample and followed it, but still for some reason nothing shows up on my error queue. I posted about this earlier but I've changed some stuff up and I'm adding more code now to make the issue more clear.

config:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
   xmlns:int-amqp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp" 
   xmlns:rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"

   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd    
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration    
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp/spring-integration-amqp.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <import resource="/org/bgt/nova/rabbit-config.xml"/>

   <int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter channel="messageOutputChannel" exchange-name="second-exchange"  amqp-template="amqpTemplate" />

   <int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter channel="messageInputChannel" error-channel = "errorInputChannel" queue-names="first" connection-factory="connectionFactory" concurrent-consumers="20" />

   <int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter channel="errorOutputChannel" exchange-name="error-exchange"  amqp-template="amqpTemplate" />

   <bean id="MessageErrorHandler" class = "firstAttempt.MessageErrorHandler"/>
   <int:channel id="messageInputChannel" />
   <int:channel id="messageOutputChannel"/>
   <int:channel id="errorOutputChannel"/>
   <int:channel id="errorInputChannel"/>

   <int:service-activator input-channel="errorInputChannel" output-channel= "errorOutputChannel" method = "handleError" >
       <bean class="firstAttempt.MessageErrorHandler"/>
   </int:service-activator>


   <int:chain input-channel="messageInputChannel" output-channel="messageOutputChannel">
       <int:header-enricher >
           <int:error-channel ref="errorInputChannel" >
           </int:error-channel>
       </int:header-enricher>
            <int:transformer method = "convert" >
                <bean class="firstAttempt.JsonObjectConverter" />
            </int:transformer>
        <int:service-activator method="transform">
             <bean class="firstAttempt.Transformer" />
        </int:service-activator>         
     <int:object-to-string-transformer />
   </int:chain>

</beans>
```

MessageErrorHandler:

```
public class MessageErrorHandler {
    public String handleError(MessagingException m) {
        return m.getMessage();
    }
}
```

Class that the transformer calls from:

```
public class QualityScorer {
    private Hashtable<String, String> table;
    private final static String csvFile = "C:\\Users\\john\\Test.csv";

public QualityScorer() throws Exception {
    table = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    initializeTable();
}

private void initializeTable() throws Exception {
     BufferedReader br = null;
      String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = ",";
   try {
       br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
               String[] data = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
            if(data.length > 6 && data[1].equals("1") && data[4].equals("0") && data[5].equals("1"))
                table.putIfAbsent(data[3], data[1]);
        }
   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
       throw new Exception("No file found");
  } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
  } finally {
        if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public float getScore(JSONObject object) throws Exception {
        float score;
        if (object == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("object");
        }
        if (!object.has("source")) {
            throw new MessagingException("Object does not have a source");
        }
         if (!object.has("employer")) {
            throw new Exception("Object does not have an employer");
        }
        String source = object.getString("Source");
        String employer = object.getString("employer");
            if (table.containsKey(employer) && !source.equals("packageOne")) {
               score = 1;
          } else {
                score = -1;
        }
        return score;
    }
}
```

Right now, the message being loaded has no source, so the program should be throwing the MessagingException to the MessageErrorHandler.

Transformer code:

```
public class Transformer {
 private QualityScorer qualityScorer;

 public Transformer() throws Exception {
  qualityScorer = new QualityScorer();
 }

 public JSONObject transform(JSONObject object) throws Exception {

     float score = qualityScorer.getScore(object);
     object.put("score", score);
    return object;
    }
}
```

All together, the program should receive a pre-loaded message from a queue, transform it and send it on to a second queue, which it does successfully if the source is provided in the pre-loaded message. I'm trying to handle errors and make it so they are sent to an error queue as a message header. This issue has been frustrating me for awhile, so help is greatly appreciated!

The error currently being shown in the stacktrace is:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: method <init>(Lorg/springframework/messaging/Message;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V not found
at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:96)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler.handleRequestMessage(ServiceActivatingHandler.java:89)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain$1.send(MessageHandlerChain.java:129)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:114)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:44)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:92)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:358)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:269)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:186)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain$1.send(MessageHandlerChain.java:129)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:114)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:44)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:92)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:358)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:269)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:186)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain.handleMessageInternal(MessageHandlerChain.java:110)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:423)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:373)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:114)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:44)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:92)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:188)
at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.access$1100(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:56)
at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.processMessage(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:246)
at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.onMessage(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:203)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:822)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:745)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$001(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:97)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$1.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:189)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1276)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:726)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1219)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1189)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1500(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:97)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1421)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

But nothing is going to the error queue.

Comment: Sorry, this is not how StackOverflow works. I provided an answer for you there, but you decided to start a new questions anyway without any particular reasons. Any way let's continue a discussion there!

Comment: Sorry, I changed a good amount of stuff and added a lot of descriptions so thought it would be easier to start fresh, but I won't do so next time! Do you think the problem could be caused by the QualityScorer class?